# How do I stealth the 'Framing Frame' heist?

Tags: payday-2

In the Framing Frame heist for the Elephant in Payday 2 you must steal select paintings from an art gallery, sell them to the senator's people and then frame the senator.

If you raise the alarm or get spotted at any point during day one or three of this heist you'll have to fight off five minutes of waves of law enforcement while the alternative mission objective completes itself.

How do I stealth the 'Framing Frame' heist?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a guide on how to complete the **Framing Frame** heist stealthily. I have included videos of each day demonstrating how the execute the plans but remember that each game has a variety of randomised elements which means you have to adapt the plan to your particular spawn.

### Day One

#### Mission Objective

The Elephant wants you to frame a senator, you're going to do this by stealing paintings that have just been sold from an art gallery, framing them in frames with cameras fitted into them and selling them to the senator. The art gallery has up to nine paintings marked with red sold stickers stickers, get them.

You need to steal at least four paintings. Get the paintings from inside the art gallery to a van outside.

#### The Plan

The art gallery has a total of six guards, one of these guards will remain stationed at the front desk unless alerted, and another will remain in the camera room until you breach it.

You will need the following abilities between your crew:

- at least one crew member with the **Dominate** ability,
- at least one crew member with the **Cleaner** ability aced to dispose of bodies,
- a crew member with the **ECM Overdrive** ability aced to get into the security room
- a crew member with **Catburglar** is optional for the fall into the room with active lasers

It's best to also get the **Camera Feeds** asset, and position one of your crew (that isn't responsible for any of the above abilities) on the camera feeds to help mark the guards. Assign another of your crew to scout around on the roof, helping the two breaching the art gallery by marking cameras and guards.

One crew member can breach via the roof if you want but my favourite method of cleaning up the guards is to draw them towards the bathroom at the front of the art gallery (there is a pickable door outside on the way up to the roof) by activating the hand dryers. This allows you to pick off the first four guards one at a time without drawing too much attention to yourself. Bag these up and hide them in one of the cubicles.

Spot the camera in the first hall from the roof before running in, and start clearing up paintings. Throw the paintings up to the spotter on the roof and he can throw them over towards the van.

Move from room to room, spotting the cameras from the roof first until you reach the room that is blocked off by lasers and then exit the building.

Normally by this point you have enough paintings to fulfil the objective but if you want or need more you can have one of your crew members breach the last room from the roof while the two of your crew move the paintings to the van. The spotter on the roof remains in position to catch paintings.

To exit, kill the guard and quickly run over to the van before the pager times out (the **Sprinter** ability is good for this) and you'll get out without an escape.

If all goes well, you'll be in and out without triggering an alarm and you'll get an achievement - **Painting Yourself Into a Corner**.

Here is a video of day one being stealthed:

### Day Two

#### Mission Objective

Get the paintings to the buyer, get the cash to the van.

#### The Plan

The plan is simple - get the paintings out of the back of your van, into a train car nearby that has a ringing phone in it. Answer the phone to start the deal with the buyer and he will request that you all get into the train car and throw the paintings out through the roof.

For each painting delivered, you will get a bag of cash. Don't throw the last painting out until you've got all of the bags of cash over to the door at the far end of the train car as doing so will start the next section of the mission. Get the cash out of the train car and head towards the getaway van - ensuring that any civilians who see you are controlled quickly, or several ECM jammers are used to stop anybody phoning the police.

If you happen to get all nine paintings on day one, you'll get an achievement once you've completed trading the bags - **Big Deal**.

Here is a video of day two being almost stealthed:

### Day Three

#### Mission Objective

The objective of day three is to break into the senator's house, steal five of his personal gadgets that can be used to gain access to his desktop computer, use the computer to gain access to the vault, plant cocaine in the vault and (optionally) steal all of the gold.

The paintings you stole on day one have been fitted with cameras, which can be viewed using a laptop on the roof. During the first stage of the heist you will want one of your crew members watching these cameras constantly, marking guards and locating the senator's gadgets.

#### The Plan

You're going to break into the senator's house, take out the first four guards and answer their pagers - dispose of the bags on the roof near the start so that nobody will find them. The fifth guard will need shouting down. You can mix this up a bit - if you get an opportunity to shout down a guard in a part of the house that nobody else is going to go, or within a timeframe where the other guards will not be a problem, then do so.

You will need the following abilities between your crew:

- at least one crew member with the **Cleaner** ability aced to dispose of bodies,
- at least one crew member with the **Dominate** ability

There isn't a security room in the house so you can't directly take control of the house cameras. You can, however, melee them to break them and clear yourself a path to the vault.

Find the five gadgets and take them to the laptop on the roof, which will allow Bain to unlock the desktop computer in the office upstairs. At this point you'll need to assign a crew member to use the computer, as it is used to open the vault and also temporarily disable the lasers in the vault.

Once the vault is open, you'll need to turn off the lasers with the desktop computer - these will only stay off for around 15 seconds but they will beep several times before reactivating.

Once you've got the gold out to the vault it should be a simple case of transporting it all to the exit point on the roof. If all goes well, you'll be in and out without triggering an alarm and you'll get an achievement - **I Wasn't Even There!**

Here is a video of day three being stealthed:

Comment: Bagging people is a skill as well (forgot the name), you should add that to the prerequisites.

Comment: **Cleaner**

- Basic (1 pt):  You deal 5% additional damage against special enemies.

- Ace (3 pt):  You can bag and throw corpses.

Comment: Changed a lot since the last update :(

Answer (score 1):

On day 2 you can easily stealth, by throwing paintings to the chopper and moving to the farthest door on the left.

Wait for it to open, place an ECM on the train car ahead of you, and dominate the 3 civilians near the van. Cable tie them, go grab your cash and move it to the van.

I've used this method to completely solo stealth this mission on overkill about 10 times. Although on day 3, I don't suggest trying to get gold out of the vault, since the lasers are only down for 15 seconds.

Comment: The lasers are the least of your problems on day 3, I find. I recently completed all three days (with all paintings, all gold) solo stealth on deathwish, without ECM's. Great challenge, but very rewarding and something I've been wanting to do for a while.